# Change background color of a table cell based on its value(Imported by XML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I've got a *html* file with a table in it, *XML* data gets imported and processed to *tbody*. Column 7 and 8 should get a background-color based on what Column 7's value is. I've got 5 different classes (5 different colors), they're at the top of my *css*

I've tried some *JQuery*: (underneath the /div in the html)

```
$("td:nth-child(7):contains('Windows Service Check')").addClass('disaster');
```

But it won't work with the xml import (tried copying the code out of the browser and it worked, copied everything under tbody and pasted it over tbody in the html file.)

I hope that somebody can help me :)

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=SITE_MIN_WIDTH, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <title>Monitoring</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <table id="Table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="NoHover">
                <th class="col1" scope='col' >Time&#9660;</th>
                <th class="col2" scope='col' ></th>
                <th class="col3" scope='col' >Client</th>
                <th class="col4" scope='col' >Status</th>
                <th class="col5" scope='col' >Site</th>
                <th class="col6" scope='col' >Host</th>
                <th class="col7" scope='col' >Problem &bull; Cause</th>
                <th class="col8" scope='col' ></th>
                <th class="col9" scope='col' >Frequency</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody id="TableData"> 
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript: (import of xml)

```
//Javascript code here
//XML Import & TBody Generation
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
getRows();
});
function getRows() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("get", "data.xml", true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        showResult(this);
    }
};
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
function showResult(xmlhttp) {
var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
removeWhitespace(xmlDoc);
var outputResult = document.getElementById("TableData");
    var rowData = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tt-outageRow");

addTableRowsFromXmlDoc(rowData,outputResult);
}
function addTableRowsFromXmlDoc(xmlNodes,tableNode) {
var theTable = tableNode.parentNode;
var outage_start, check_status, client_name;
for (i=0; i<xmlNodes.length; i++) {
newRow = tableNode.insertRow(i);
    outage_start = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    outage_start.innerHTML = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[4].firstChild.nodeValue;
    check_status = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    check_status.innerHTML = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    check_status = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    check_status.innerHTML = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[7].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[3].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[5].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[6].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[8].firstChild.nodeValue;
}
theTable.appendChild(tableNode);
}
function removeWhitespace(xml) {
var loopIndex;
for (loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < xml.childNodes.length; loopIndex++)
{
    var currentNode = xml.childNodes[loopIndex];
    if (currentNode.nodeType == 1)
    {
        removeWhitespace(currentNode);
    }
    if (!(/\S/.test(currentNode.nodeValue)) && (currentNode.nodeType == 3))
    {
        xml.removeChild(xml.childNodes[loopIndex--]);
    }
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
/*CSS for color classes*/
td.disaster {   background-color: #E45858
}
td.high     {   background-color: #E87658
}
td.average  {   background-color: #FEA058
}
td.warning  {   background-color: #FEC858
}
td.information  {   background-color: #7498FE
}
/*CSS for main elements*/
div {   max-width: 2600px;
        display: block;
}
body {  font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
table {     text-align: left;
            border-collapse: collapse;
}
th  {   font-size: 75%; 
        font-weight: normal;
        color:  #768C98;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #DCE2E4;
}
td  {   font-size: 75%; 
        color: #1F2C33;
        height: 25px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}   
/*CSS for Hover*/
td:nth-child(1):hover   {   text-decoration: underline;
}
td:nth-child(1) {   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
td:nth-child(2) {   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
tr.NoHover:hover{   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
tr:hover {      background-color: #E8F5FF;
}
/*Column specific CSS*/
th.col1 {   text-align: right;
            width: 240px;
            padding-right: 18px
}
th.col2 {   width: 11px;
            padding: none;  
}
th.col3 {   text-align: left;
            width: 188px;
            padding-left: 10px;
}
th.col4 {   text-align: left;
            width: 70px;
}
th.col5 {   text-align: left;
            width: 77px;
            padding-left: 82px;
}
th.col6 {   text-align: left;
            width: 430px;
}
th.col7 {   text-align: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 497px;
}
th.col8 {   text-align: left;
        width: 498px;
}
th.col9 {   text-align: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 75px;
}
td:nth-child(1) {   text-align: right;
                color: #0274B8;
                padding-right: 18px;
                border-right: 2px solid #AAD6F0;
                border-bottom: none;
}
td:nth-child(2) {   color: white;
                border-bottom: none;
                width: 11px;
                padding: none;
}
td:nth-child(3) {   text-align: left;
                text-decoration: underline dotted; 
                padding-left: 10px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
td:nth-child(4) {   text-align: left;
                color: #DC0000;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
td:nth-child(5) {   text-align: right;
                text-decoration: underline dotted;
                padding-right: 15px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
td:nth-child(6) {   text-align: left;
                text-decoration: underline dotted;  
                border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;                       
}
td:nth-child(7) {   text-align: left;
                text-decoration: underline dotted ;
                padding-left: 10px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
td:nth-child(8) {   text-align: left;
                text-decoration: underline dotted;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
td:nth-child(9) {   text-align: left;
                padding-left: 10px; 
                border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tt-outage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tt-outageRow>
    <outage_type>1</outage_type>
    <client_name>Client 1</client_name>
    <site_name>Site 1</site_name>
    <device_description>PC1</device_description>
    <outage_start>2017-11-22</outage_start>
    <check_description>Windows Service Check</check_description>
    <check_cause>Unable to open service</check_cause>
    <check_status>FAILING</check_status>
    <check_frequency>24x7</check_frequency>
    <outage_color>#E45858</outage_color>
  </tt-outageRow>
  <tt-outageRow>
    <outage_type>1</outage_type>
    <client_name>Client 2</client_name>
    <site_name>Site 2</site_name>
    <device_description>PC2</device_description>
    <outage_start>2017-11-22</outage_start>
    <check_description>Windows Service Check</check_description>
    <check_cause>Unable to open service</check_cause>
    <check_status>FAILING</check_status>
    <check_frequency>24x7</check_frequency>
    <outage_color>#E87658</outage_color>
  </tt-outageRow>
  <tt-outageRow>
    <outage_type>1</outage_type>
    <client_name>Client 3</client_name>
    <site_name>Site 3</site_name>
    <device_description>PC3</device_description>
    <outage_start>2017-11-22</outage_start>
    <check_description>Windows Service Check</check_description>
    <check_cause>Unable to open service</check_cause>
    <check_status>FAILING</check_status>
    <check_frequency>24x7</check_frequency>
    <outage_color>#EAEEFO</outage_color>
  </tt-outageRow>
  <tt-outageRow>
    <outage_type>1</outage_type>
    <client_name>Client 4</client_name>
    <site_name>Site 4</site_name>
    <device_description>PC4</device_description>
    <outage_start>2017-11-22</outage_start>
    <check_description>Windows Service Check</check_description>
    <check_cause>Unable to open service</check_cause>
    <check_status>FAILING</check_status>
    <check_frequency>24x7</check_frequency>
    <outage_color>#FEC858</outage_color>
  </tt-outageRow>
  <tt-outageRow>
    <outage_type>1</outage_type>
    <client_name>Client 5</client_name>
    <site_name>Site 5</site_name>
    <device_description>PC5</device_description>
    <outage_start>2017-11-22</outage_start>
    <check_description>Windows Service Check</check_description>
    <check_cause>Unable to open service</check_cause>
    <check_status>FAILING</check_status>
    <check_frequency>24x7</check_frequency>
    <outage_color>#7498FE</outage_color>
  </tt-outageRow>
</tt-outage>
```

Comment: When do you call the jQuery code? I do not see the addClass line in it.

Comment: Can you make codepen, jsbin with your code so we can see it in action ?

Comment: How do I import an xml in those programs? @Zvezdas1989

Comment: I used the jQuery code inside of the html file underneath the /div. @epascarello but I removed because it did'nt work

Comment: well that would try to select the rows BEFORE it is added.  You need to run it after you add the rows....

Comment: @epascarello
IT WORKS, placed it underneath _theTable.appendChild(tableNode);_ in the  _function addTableRowsFromXmlDoc(xmlNodes,tableNode)_

Comment: @epascarello Do you have a way to make column 7 _and 8_ the same color based on column 7's data

Answer (score 0):

I guess you call your jQuery construction after the table is built. I would do that at the point of generating a row. Instead of using a complicated jQuery traversal through all DOM elements that safisfy your selector, which is always expensive, I would test a value that you get from XML against your 'disaster' value (you might want to move it to a variable or a set of variables, but that's a different story).

Do something like this:

```
//in the beginning
var disasterStr = 'Windows Service Check',
    disasterClass = 'disaster';

//...inside of your table building loop...
if (xmlNodes[i].childNodes[6].firstChild.nodeValue === disasterStr) {
    $(client_name).addClass(disasterClass);
    //or, using Vanilla
    //client_name.className = client_name.className + ' ' + disasterClass;
}
//...
```

Besides that, you don't need to redeclare variables in the loop, so you loop will better look like this:

```
var outage_start, check_status, client_name;
for (i=0; i<xmlNodes.length; i++) {
    newRow = tableNode.insertRow(i);
    outage_start = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    outage_start.innerHTML = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[4].firstChild.nodeValue;
    check_status = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    check_status.innerHTML = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    check_status = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    check_status.innerHTML = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[7].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[2].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[3].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[5].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[6].firstChild.nodeValue;
    client_name  = newRow.insertCell(newRow.cells.length);
    client_name.innerHTML  = xmlNodes[i].childNodes[8].firstChild.nodeValue;
}
```

There are programming style issues with this code too, but this is also another story. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I don't really know stuff about scripting (What I know I learned by going trough the web to find something that will let me import an xml) So I know very little about that. 

I tried your code, put the beginning code in the beginning of the file and put the if code on multiple places in the loop, but it did not work. I tried the same with the beginning code in the beginning of the function addTableRowsFromXmlDoc but that did not work eighter.

I altered the variables in the loop, worked like it should so thats good.

Comment: I GOT IT WORKING 
Placed my original jQuery in the all the way down like this:
function addTableRowsFromXmlDoc(xmlNodes,tableNode) {
........................
 theTable.appendChild(tableNode);
 $("td:nth-child(7):contains('Windows Service Check')").addClass('disaster');
}

Comment: Do you have a way to give the 8th column that color to?

Comment: well it really is a new question, but `td.foo, td.foo + td { background-color: red; }`